# Is it possible in a Java server to get the SSL/TLS cipher suites offered by the client?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Is it possible in a Java server to get the cipher suites offered by the client at a time of negotiating? There is a method to get negotiated cipher suite:

```
String cipherSuite = someSSLServerSocket.getSession().getCipherSuite();
```

I can test remote client with `openssl`, `nmap`, but that's not the case.

Comment: If you are the client, all you do in a single handshake is find out if the server will negotiate a given ciphersuite or not ("supports" is too nebulous a word here). By trying successive handshakes you can enumerate each ciphersuite, offer it to the server, and see if it will handshake and establish a connection with you using the ciphersuite. Once you have finished going through each ciphersuite, you'll know which ones the server is prepared to accept. Or, you can just let [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) do it for you.

Comment: No, as a server. The client sends available cipher suites during handshake. And the question - how to get that information? Perhaps by extending SSLServerSocket?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention. Let me see what I can find.

Comment: Sorry, it appears that information is thrown away after it is used. You can see an object of class `ClientHello` is created at line 209 of [`sun.security.ssl.ServerHandShaker`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker.java). The client-offered ciphersuites are a field in that class, but after that handshake message is processed nothing is retained. I'm not sure how to customize an SSL class to retain that info.

Comment: Getting closer :) So we need to override `processMessage(...)` constructor.

Comment: I found an interesting approach [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExamples), at the bottom of page, will test soon.

Comment: It looks like I found fantastic solution :), and now theoretically at the moment can read entire `ClientHello` message and later, after reading, have usual server socket.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. I hadn't noticed the utility of [createSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket-java.net.Socket-java.io.InputStream-boolean-) before, but now it seems obvious.